# System calls make use of which mode?

Tags: unix, system-calls

System calls make use of which mode(s)?

1. Kernel mode
2. User mode
3. System mode
4. Both kernel and user mode

Answer (score 0):

Users use system calls to access kernel functions. So I guess (4).